# Prefetch script from server (not from cache) for next time

Tags: html

If browser has a cached version of a JS file, I want it to be loaded and executed.
I also want this cache to be refreshed with a fresh copy from the server after each execution.

```
<script src="script.js"></script> <!-- cache-control: private, max-age=86400 -->
```

script.js

```
var prefechscript = document.createElement('link'); 
prefechscript.href = 'script.js';
prefechscript.rel = 'prefetch'; 
prefechscript.as = 'script'; 
document.head.appendChild(prefechscript);
```

But this method does not work because the browser prefetch from cache.
Would you have a way to achieve this?

I wish `<link>` has an attribute `fetch-from-server`, so it will always pull a copy from server and store it in cache if server respond with a `cache-control`.

I am looking to have a solution at least for Chrome.

Edit:
In my case, the URL of the script tag `<script src="script.js"></script>` cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the URL of a resource that was cached you will receive a new version. A simple way is to use the current time to do this:

```
const prefetchscript = document.createElement('link'); 
prefetchscript.href = 'script.js';
prefetchscript.rel = 'prefetch'; 
prefetchscript.as = 'script'; 
document.head.appendChild(prefetchscript);
window.setTimeout( ()=>{ let now = new Date(); prefetchscript.href = 'script.js?t='+ now.getTime(); } );
```

Comment: Are you sure? From my test, the next time page is loaded the call to `<script src="script.js"></script>` does not use the version prefetched. I think because cache key is URI based.

Comment: Maybe the issue lies with you mixing a link element and the script tag for the same resource – try changing the src attribute of the script element to add time – or fetch it with a XHR call .. adding something **new** to the URL is key, current time guarantees no repetition if you don't try to do it more than once every millisecond.

Comment: Browser is caching `script.js?t=1` in another cache than `script.js?t=2`. Also I can't change my `<script>` src, it will always be the same url in my case.  So yes I could force fetch a new version with another t value but won't be able to use it.

Comment: I meant change the requested URL by adding the variable query string (like "t=1234") not the filename - that would work too, google:pagespeed does use that approach.

Comment: By just changing the value of t , it still does not works.
<script src="script.js?t=1"></script>
<link href="script.js?t=2" rel="prefetch" as="script"/>
The version cached of <link> does not refresh the version cached in <script src="script.js?t=1">
In my edit, I said I cannot change url (and parameter of <script> overtime).
Cache key is URI (with path + parameters) based.